# how to make a timer on JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, timer

I have a JS game similar to snake how can i set a timer for the game where when the game ends it displays game over, shows the score of the player, and has a play again button?

Comment: This is kind of on a sharp edge between game development and general coding which would be rather placed on stackoverflow..

Answer (score 0):

## Use `setTimeout`

```
setTimeout(function(){code here},seconds*1000)
```

The code will run after X seconds.